# Django ajax HttpResponse json error Unexpected token d

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, json

I am trying to do a Django ajax HttpResponse json using [medium-editor](https://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor).

view.py

```
def test(request, union_id):
if request.is_ajax():
    t = Union.objects.get(id=union_id)
    message = json.loads(request.body)
    t.description = message['description']['value']
    t.save()
    return HttpResponse(message, mimetype="application/json")
else:
    message = "Not Ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Jquery (Updated)

```
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#savecontentObj').click(function() {
        var contentObj = editor.serialize();
        obj = JSON.stringify(contentObj);
        $.ajax({
          url:"update",
            type: "POST",
            data: obj,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success:function(response){
                console.log('success');
            },
            complete:function(){
                console.log('complete');
            },
            error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
                console.log(obj);
            }
        });
    });
```

console.log

```
SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token d"}
{"description":{"value":"<p>dddddd</p>"}}
complete
```

It is saving 'description' to the database but I am not achieving success in the httpresponse as you can see in the console.log.

Many thanks!

## Updated

url.py

```
url(r'^(?P<union_id>\d+)/update$', views.test),
```

Comment: Try stringifying the data: `data: JSON.stringify(obj)`.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that here: `obj = JSON.stringify(contentObj);`

Comment: oh yeah sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def test(request, union_id):
if request.is_ajax():
    t = Union.objects.get(id=union_id)
    t.description = request.POST.get('description',None)
    t.save()
    HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict(status='updated')), mimetype="application/json")
else:
    message = "Not Ajax"
    HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict(status="Not Ajax")), mimetype="application/json")

$('#savecontentObj').click(function() {
        var contentObj = editor.serialize();
        $.ajax({
          url:"update",
            type: "POST",
            data: contentObj,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data.success);
            },
            complete:function(){
                console.log('complete');
            },
            error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
                console.log(obj);
            }
        });
    });
```

Make sure your ajax url is not according to your views method and also  csrf token must  exist in serialize value.

Comment: With this view I get `IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'description' cannot be null")`. I updated with my url.py code

Comment: you can debug your code just place import pdb;pdb.set_trace() after line t = Union.objects.get(id=union_id). you have get debugging console . and you can check description exist in request.POST. if not check your serialize values.

Comment: I get success with `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict(status='updated')), mimetype="application/json")`. Thank you very much @Yogesh, I will keep experimenting with this

Comment: Yes, I did. It needed `json.dumps` on `return`. Thank you very much!