# How to pass data from javascript to django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm pretty new to Django (and web development) and find myself struggling with this problem. I'm able to pass the data from Django to javascript
HTML

```
 function load_led(){
    {% for leds in led %}

        var str2 = "{{leds.name}}"
        var x = {{leds.x}}
        var y = {{leds.y}}
        var w = 30
        var h = 30
        var fill = "{{leds.color}}"

        document.getElementById("FirstName").value = str2;
        document.getElementById("xposition").value = x;
        document.getElementById("yposition").value = y;
        document.getElementById("status").value = fill;

        add1(x,y,fill);
    {% endfor %} 
}
```

Now I change the values of Elements and then want to pass this values again to Django so that I can update my database. So how can I pass the values from javascript or from HTML page

Comment: You can take example from there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259988/django-ajax-httpresponse-json-error-unexpected-token-d/21260734#21260734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an ajax call or similar to pass data to the server.  You can make it very fast with jquery

Comment: Can you please explain with the example or can you please post the link of sample example in which ajax is explained ?

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465711/how-do-i-post-with-jquery-ajax-in-django