# Refreshing context variable with ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, xmlhttprequest

getting null instead of the refreshed value when the event is triggered in the template, getting the correct value in the terminal for example `success 6`. How do I get the real value to render out instead of null, feel free to improve this question if you see anything wrong. Cheer!

I've searched a lot in the community and tried lots of things but couldn't find what's causing the issue, I hope someone can help me!

reproducible repo: https://github.com/bettstogain/reproducible_shop/tree/main/env

This is my code:

```
path('ajax_update/', views.ajax_update, name="ajax_update"),
```

view

```
#bagstuff is a function that sees if the user is authenticated and does get_or_create
#or is not authenticated and refers to use the cookie

def ajax_update(request):
    stuff = bagstuff(request)
    bag = stuff['bag']

    # if_ajax returns, request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax and request.method == "GET":

        #trying to get the bag value after the event is triggered
        if bag:
            print("success", bag)

            #trying to get the bag and put it in JsonResponse
            data_attribute = request.GET.get(bag)
            #print(data_attribute) -- this prints null

        return JsonResponse(data_attribute, safe=False, status=200)
    else:
        print("failed")

    context = {"bag": bag}
```

template:

```
<script>
    var update_bag_url = "{% url 'store:ajax_update' %}";
</script>
```

javascript:

```
function update_bag() {
    // optional: don't cache ajax to force the content to be fresh
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    // specify loading spinner
    var spinner = "<img alt='loading..' />";

    $("#lil-icon-two").html(spinner).load(update_bag_url);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Ajax in Django-templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374269/how-to-use-ajax-in-django-templates)

Comment: sorry, it doesn't, also by rendering I meant to update the specific class without reloading the page, I believe ajax is used for that.

Comment: It's not reproducible. (i) There's no `id="lil-icon-two"`, (ii) `update_bag` isn't called, (iii) `context` is not  stored or passed anywhere.

Comment: @aaron Added repo, hope that sheds enough light! thnx!

Comment: What's the expected value of `data_attribute = request.GET.get(bag)`?

Comment: @aaron the expected value is the total quantity number of the bag after someone hits add to cart

Comment: Isn't that just `data_attribute = bag`?

Comment: @aaron omg and it works!!!! Thanks sooo muchhh!!!! Ig I misunderstood something about adding to JSON with ajax only works with GET.get but it works now! thx to u! means a lot haha